# Cannot read the tooltip content

Tags: bug

**Tooltip is getting hidden behind the header.**

Please increase the z-index of css-tooltip since it is getting hidden behind the header.

[image: Please check the area marked in red. Tooltip hidden behind header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by increasing the css-tooltip z-index.
[image: After increasing tooltip it looks like this]